# Shell command to save output in subfolders after using find?

Tags: shell, find

I have a main directory with several subfolders. Each subfolder contains a *.fna file and I want my script to do the command with the fna file and write the output back in the subfolder. 
As my script is now, it makes one big file in the main directory, but I want the output per subfolder, in each subfolder.

```
find * |grep fna$ |while read fna ; do formatdb -i $fna -p F ; blastall -p blastn/ 
-d $fna -i plasmiddb_genes_renamed.fsa -m 8 -e 1E-30 |while read hit ; do echo/
$fna $hit ; done ; done > $fna.blast_plasmidrefdb.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways

- Capture the `dirname` of the *$fna* value

  > find * |grep fna$ |while read fna ; do **fdir=`dirname $fna`;** formatdb -i $fna -p F ; blastall -p blastn/ 
  >   -d $fna -i plasmiddb_genes_renamed.fsa -m 8 -e 1E-30 |while read hit ; do echo/
  >   $fna $hit **| tee ${fdir}/out.txt**; done ; done > $fna.blast_plasmidrefdb.out
- use the *$fna* path with a suffix : e.g. ${fna}.out

  > find * |grep fna$ |while read fna ; do formatdb -i $fna -p F ; blastall -p blastn/ 
  >   -d $fna -i plasmiddb_genes_renamed.fsa -m 8 -e 1E-30 |while read hit ; do echo/
  >   $fna $hit ***| tee ${fna}.out***; done ; done > $fna.blast_plasmidrefdb.out

used `| tee` in case you wanted to ALSO capture in one file still.

compressing the `one liner` even more

> for fna in $(find . -type f -name "*.fna"); do formatdb -i $fna -p F ; blastall -p blastn/ -d $fna -i plasmiddb_genes_renamed.fsa -m 8 -e 1E-30 | tee ${fna}.out; done

Answer (score 0):

If your `find` supports it, use -execdir:

```
find . -name '*.fna' -execdir sh -c '{ 
    formatdb -i $0 -p F; blastall -p blastn -d $0 \
        -i /path/to/plasmiddb_genes_renaed.fsa -m 8 -e 1E-30; 
    } > $0.output' {} \;
```

That will generate an output-file for each *.fna file in the directory containing the *.fna file.  Note that you need to use a full path to plasmiddb_genes_renaed.fsa.